# Proper aggregating metrics in PromQL and perform basic math operations for alerts

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager, alerts

I have a batch job that adds nodes to a graph sequentially. This job takes up to 2 days depending on the size of the graph and its complexity. I am trying to create an alert that will help me track down issues while these nodes are getting added. For that, I created the following 3 metrics:

number_of_success_nodes_total (number of successfully added nodes)
number_of_failed_nodes_total (number of nodes that failed when getting added)
all_nodes_total (sum of 1 and 2)

I need to create an alert every time the metric #2 surpasses 5% of the total requests.

Something like:

```
number_of_failed_nodes_total >= all_nodes_total * 0.05
```

All the 3 metrics have the same following tags/labels:
id (there are 8 fixed values, eg.: US, CA, AU, etc)
name (every time the batch job starts, we are going to have a new value here. The name is composed of the year + version incremented. E.g.: 2023.v1)

I have to run this job once a month for each of the 8 fixed ids. So the alert that I want to create should be triggered when the above condition is met, but only for the metrics within the same id and name groups.

How can I properly aggregate/group metrics by labels to trigger the above-described alert?

Since I have to run the jobs once a month and they take up to 2 days to finish, I thought that maybe I could disconsider the name label and add a time range of up to 2 days in the past to have something like this:

```
sum by(id)(

 rate(number_of_failed_nodes_total{_namespace_="batchJob"}[2d]) >= 
 rate(all_nodes_total{_namespace_="batchJob"}[2d]) * 0.05

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create alerting rule with you exact expression. I changed `>=` for `>` to not create alerts when all metrics 0 (at the beginning of your task).

```yaml
  rules:
  - alert: HighFailureRate
    expr: number_of_failed_nodes_total > all_nodes_total * 0.05
    annotations:
      summary: High failure rate
      description: {{ $value }} nodes failed
```

You don't have to employ some clever tricks for this rule, because once you job stops to supply metrics to Prometheus, existing values will became stale, and rules will not be evaluated.

That being said, I would like to note, that such metrics are not really [Prometheus style](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/). More "classical" way would be to have metric like `number_of_nodes_total` with label `result`.

For this case `expr` in above rule would be

```
number_of_nodes_total{result="failed"} > ignoring (result) sum by (id,name)(number_of_nodes_total) * 0.05
```